# additive subgroup of real numbers with non empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

G is an additive subgroup of real numbers with a nonempty interior.Then G is all the real numbers.what is the exact proof?

Comment: This is basically Archimedean property.

Answer (score 3):

Let A be  the subgroup of the real line R with non-empty interior.Let x be a point in the interior of A. Then there exist a neighborhood$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ containing x which is contained in A. As A is a subgroup n$(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ for any integer n will belongs to A. In this way you will get A=R.